# Firebase cloud function using Expo-server-sdk

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send push notifications using Firebase cloud functions.

I'm using  https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node

When I try to deploy I'm getting some errors. (only getting the errors with earlier code and package required, and not when just deploying my hello world function)

the code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { Expo } = require("expo-server-sdk");

// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });
  response.send("Hello from Firebase");
});

exports.notifications = functions.firestore
  .document("notifications/{id}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    // console.log("-----snap", snap.data());
    // console.log("-----context", context);
    // console.log("-----context.params", context.params);

    // Create a new Expo SDK client
    // optionally providing an access token if you have enabled push security
    let expo = new Expo({ accessToken: process.env.EXPO_ACCESS_TOKEN });

    // Create the messages that you want to send to clients
    let messages = [];
    for (let pushToken of somePushTokens) {
      // Each push token looks like ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

      // Check that all your push tokens appear to be valid Expo push tokens
      if (!Expo.isExpoPushToken(pushToken)) {
        console.error(`Push token ${pushToken} is not a valid Expo push token`);
        continue;
      }

      // Construct a message (see https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/)
      messages.push({
        to: pushToken,
        sound: "default",
        body: "This is a test notification",
        data: { withSome: "data" }
      });
    }

    // The Expo push notification service accepts batches of notifications so
    // that you don't need to send 1000 requests to send 1000 notifications. We
    // recommend you batch your notifications to reduce the number of requests
    // and to compress them (notifications with similar content will get
    // compressed).
    let chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages);
    let tickets = [];
    (async function test() {
      // Send the chunks to the Expo push notification service. There are
      // different strategies you could use. A simple one is to send one chunk at a
      // time, which nicely spreads the load out over time:
      for (let chunk of chunks) {
        try {
          let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
          console.log(ticketChunk);
          tickets.push(...ticketChunk);
          // NOTE: If a ticket contains an error code in ticket.details.error, you
          // must handle it appropriately. The error codes are listed in the Expo
          // documentation:
          // https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#individual-errors
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
    })();

    // Later, after the Expo push notification service has delivered the
    // notifications to Apple or Google (usually quickly, but allow the the service
    // up to 30 minutes when under load), a "receipt" for each notification is
    // created. The receipts will be available for at least a day; stale receipts
    // are deleted.
    //
    // The ID of each receipt is sent back in the response "ticket" for each
    // notification. In summary, sending a notification produces a ticket, which
    // contains a receipt ID you later use to get the receipt.
    //
    // The receipts may contain error codes to which you must respond. In
    // particular, Apple or Google may block apps that continue to send
    // notifications to devices that have blocked notifications or have uninstalled
    // your app. Expo does not control this policy and sends back the feedback from
    // Apple and Google so you can handle it appropriately.
    let receiptIds = [];
    for (let ticket of tickets) {
      // NOTE: Not all tickets have IDs; for example, tickets for notifications
      // that could not be enqueued will have error information and no receipt ID.
      if (ticket.id) {
        receiptIds.push(ticket.id);
      }
    }

    let receiptIdChunks = expo.chunkPushNotificationReceiptIds(receiptIds);
    (async function testTwo() {
      // Like sending notifications, there are different strategies you could use
      // to retrieve batches of receipts from the Expo service.
      for (let chunk of receiptIdChunks) {
        try {
          let receipts = await expo.getPushNotificationReceiptsAsync(chunk);
          console.log(receipts);

          // The receipts specify whether Apple or Google successfully received the
          // notification and information about an error, if one occurred.
          for (let receiptId in receipts) {
            let { status, message, details } = receipts[receiptId];
            if (status === "ok") {
              continue;
            } else if (status === "error") {
              console.error(
                `There was an error sending a notification: ${message}`
              );
              if (details && details.error) {
                // The error codes are listed in the Expo documentation:
                // https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#individual-errors
                // You must handle the errors appropriately.
                console.error(`The error code is ${details.error}`);
              }
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
    })();
  });
```

the errors

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'appName'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (72.9 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function helloWorld(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function notifications(us-central1)...

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        helloWorld(us-central1)
        notifications(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function helloWorld in region us-central1
- Error Failed to update function notifications in region us-central1


$ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'appName'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (72.9 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function helloWorld(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function notifications(us-central1)...

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        helloWorld(us-central1)
        notifications(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function helloWorld in region us-central1
- Error Failed to update function notifications in region us-central1
```

I'm not sure what to even try at this point. did some searching and it doesn't seem to be that common of an issue and haven't found any solutions at this point.

Let me know if I should be supplying more info.

I can run  $ firebase functions:log or ...-debug and share the output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Would you show the error through `firebase-debug.log`? I managed to replicate `helloWorld` and it was working fine on my end.

Comment: Sure, can you give me the exact command to run?

Comment: when I don't import the package & just have the hello world function, it deploys just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package was installed in the node modules folder of the project and not the node-modules for the functions folder.